# How access specifier affect static methods?

Tags: java

what will be the advantages and disadvantages of putting public with static methods ?
As in any case We can access those using class name !

Comment: Static and access level modifiers are two different, unrelated things.

Comment: @MarounMaroun thats what i am asking what will be the affect of putting public / default(none) with static methods ?

Comment: Making them [public](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) is one thing, and making them [static](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) is another thing.

Comment: @dineshkandpal read more about access modifiers. and nothing to do with static or non static

Comment: @dineshkandpal access level is not different for static methods

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Java, difference between default, public, protected, and private](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-difference-between-default-public-protected-and-private)

Answer (score 3):

Without specifying an access control modifier, members of a class (static as instance) use by default the `package private` modifier.

You should refer to the [Controlling Access to Members of a Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) documentation :

> Access level modifiers determine whether other classes can use a
>   particular field or invoke a particular method. There are two levels
>   of access control:
>
> At the top level—public, or `package-private` (no explicit modifier).
>
> At the member level—public, `private`, `protected`, or `package-private` (no
>   explicit modifier).

Why a `static` method should necessarily be `public` ?

As for instance methods, you may also need to make them `private` or `package private`.

`static` has nevertheless a corner case : the `protected static` modifier should be avoided as misleading and contradictory in the intention.

Answer (score 2):

They are not. And no, you cannot access private static methods from another class.

Comment: i am asking difference between public vs default(none) not between public and private !

Comment: @dineshkandpal The links in my comment on your question should answer you.

Comment: @dineshkandpal same answer

Answer (score 1):

As Maroun has mentioned, access level modifiers are different than the static modifier.

By default, methods and variables are `package-private` when there is no access modifier. This means that they are restricted to your "package" or your project.

`public` means that all methods in all packages can see/use them.

`private` means that the method can only be used by that class.

The `static` modifier means that the class doesn't need to be instantiated to use the method/variable.

For a more in depth article on modifiers, please refer to this website: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_modifier_types.htm